Deliberate error in decryption by modifying the encryption
Are you aware of any cryptosystem in which the following is doable:
The sender of information can deliberately manipulate the encryption process such that some controlled error is produced in the decryption at the recipient side without degrading the security?
context: Assume that the introduction of some level of error in the recipient is desirable. In other words, we want the receiver get some noisy version of the plaintext. Obviously, one can always blur the plaintext first and apply the encryption to the blurred/noisy version of the plaintext. Instead of this approach, can we modify the cryptosystem in which the complexity of the encryption is reduced for the purpose of introducing error at the recipient side, while the security remains intact?

Although it won't change the complexity, would a bit flip of a stream cipher (or CTR mode for block ciphers) be an option? That flips a single bit of the plaintext after decryption. And if you want more errors, then simply flip more bits. If you want authenticated mode then you should do this before calculating the authentication tag of course, or you must find out before verification which bit had been flipped and correct before running verification.

@MaartenBodewes Thanks. That's of course an option, but I am mainly looking for something that has an advantage over the first approach mentioned in the "context". This advantage could be a reduction in complexity.

Alright, but I'm wondering if you can find something that is less complex than a stream cipher.

Suppose you encode an image in a progressive file format (the kind where on a website a blurry version of the image loads first, and progressively gets clearer as more of the file loads). Then you encrypt the image. Suppose the receiver decrypts only the first half of the file. This is (1) a way to modify the encryption scheme (2) that is obviously faster than the usual decryption, (3) that results in a  "noisy" version of the correct/final plaintext, (4) and doesn't change security properties (at least not CPA). Does this count as an example of what you have in mind?

The CKKS FHE scheme can be seen as essentially what you want, though one doesn't directly improve efficiency (instead, the improvements are indirect, though still very real/important). That being said, the security can be hurt in somewhat subtle ways, as initially noticed in Li and Micciancio's work. The way this subtly harms security is likely of interest to you, so I'll include a brief description below.
Li and Micciancio notice that if decryption may be wrong, then querying $O(m) :=\mathsf{Dec}(\mathsf{Enc}(m))$ yields new information not available to an IND-CPA adversary, but which may still be thought of as plausibly "passively observable" (such queries are quite far from typical IND-CCA-type attacks).
For correct cryptosystems, $O(m) = m$ clearly gives no new information (and so these new types of queries give adversaries no power).
They then leveraged (a homomorphic version of) $O$ to get key recovery attacks on CKKS.
This is to say that this enhanced notion of security (they call $\mathsf{IND}\text{-}\mathsf{CPA}^{\mathsf{D}}$, for ind-cpa with decryption oracles, though only for "honestly generated" ciphertexts) is only equivalent to IND-CPA security for correct cryptosystems, and for incorrect cryptosystems (of practical interest!) things can break down entirely.
So when introducing errors to the plaintext during decryption, one should probably consider the $\mathsf{IND}\text{-}\mathsf{CPA}^{\mathsf{D}}$ model, rather than standard IND-CPA.

That's valuable indeed, thank you.
